# Points of abelian varieties over purely transcendental extensions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties

I heard about the result in the theory of abelian varieties which says the following: given an abelian variety $X$ defined over a field $k$ and a purely transcendental extension $k\subset L\subset L'$ we have that the group $X(L)$ of $L$-points is the same as the group $X(L')$. Could you give me (the reference for) the proof of this result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This follows from the following well-known lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$. Then any map $f \colon \mathbb P^1 \to A$ is constant.

*Proof 1.* The map $f$ induces a map on the Albanese $f_* \colon \operatorname{Alb}_{\mathbb P^1} \to \operatorname{Alb}_A$ sitting in a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb P^1 & \stackrel{f}\longrightarrow & A \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \operatorname{Alb}_{\mathbb P^1} & \stackrel{f_*}\longrightarrow &\ \operatorname{Alb}_A. \end{array}$$
But $\operatorname{Alb}_{\mathbb P^1}$ is trivial, and the map $A \to \operatorname{Alb}_A$ is an isomorphism. $\square$

*Proof 2.* After translating on $A$, we may assume $f(0) = 0$. The point $0\in \mathbb P^1$ is the identity element for two different group structures: the open subscheme $\mathbb P^1 - \infty$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb G_a$, and $\mathbb P^1 - \{\infty, 1\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb G_m$. Then $f|_{\mathbb G_a}$ and $f|_{\mathbb G_m}$ are both group homomorphisms, which is impossible unless $f$ is constant. $\square$

*Proof 3.* There is a third proof using triviality of $\Omega_A$ and the fact that $\Omega_{\mathbb P^1}$ has no global sections. See e.g. [Bhatt's notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/abelian_varieties.pdf), **Cor. 3.6**. $\square$

**Corollary.** Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$, and let $C$ be a rational curve (not necessarily smooth or proper). Then any map $f \colon C \to A$ is constant.

*Proof.* By assumption, there is an open $U \subseteq C$ that is isomorphic to an open in $\mathbb P^1$. Moreover, $f|_U$ extends uniquely to a morphism $\mathbb P^1 \to A$ because $A$ is proper. Hence, $f|_U$ is constant. Because $U$ is dense, this forces $f$ to be constant. $\square$

**Corollary.** Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$, and let $Y$ be a rational variety (not necessarily smooth or proper). Then any morphism $f \colon Y \to A$ is constant.

*Proof.* It suffices to prove that $f$ is constant on a big open, so we may replace $Y$ by an open $U \subseteq Y$ that is isomorphic to an open in $\mathbb P^n_k$. Then $Y$ is covered by (not necessarily proper) rational curves $C \subseteq Y$. By the corollary above, we conclude that $f$ is constant on all of those, hence $f$ is constant. $\square$

The answer to the OP now follows: $L$-points of $X$ are the same as the $L$-points of $X_L = X \times_k L$, so we may assume that $L = k$. Then a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} L' \to A$ spreads out to a rational variety $Y$ with function field $L'$, hence is constant (i.e. comes from a $k$-point) by the arguments above.

Comment: I think the simplest proof of the lemma uses that there are no nontrivial finite, etale covers of $\mathbb{P}^1$.  Thus, for every odd prime $\ell$ different from the characteristic, every morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $A$ factors through the "multiplication-by-$\ell$" morphism.  For any ample invertible sheaf $L$ on $A$, this implies that the degree of the pullback of $L$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is divisible by $\ell$ (by the Theorem of the Cube).  Thus, the degree is zero, and the morphism is constant.

Comment: @JasonStarr: ah, that's pretty neat. I'm a little agnostic as to which proof is simpler, but the one you gave is certainly pretty nice.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9066/is-there-any-rational-curve-on-an-abelian-variety/

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Ah, I thought I had seen that question (and answer) here before, but I couldn't find it when I was writing. Thanks!

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand in your proof: why the morphism $\mathrm{Spec} L'\to A$ spreads out to a rational variety?

Comment: Hi Remy, it seems that your argument uses the fact that the transcendence degree of L'/k is finite. However the OP claims this is true for any purely transcendental extension?

Comment: @AnnaAbasheva: if $L'$ is the function field of $\mathbb A^n$ (or $\mathbb P^n$), then any morphism $\operatorname{Spec} L' \to X$ to any finite type $k$-scheme $X$ spreads out to some open neighbourhood of the generic point in $\mathbb A^n$. If you don't know this, you should do this as an exercise. (Hint: first think about the case that $X$ is affine. Use that $X$ is of finite type.)

Comment: @BenLim: any $k(x_1,\ldots)$-point of a finite type $k$-scheme factors through the finitely generated extension $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for some $n$.

Comment: Could you explain why the restrictions of f are both group homomorphisms in Proof 2.? The rigidity lemma requires the source to be proper.